# Java static enum method to return a default enum value

Tags: java, enums

I want to create a static method for my enum called default(), which will return a default enum value. How would I go about doing this without getting a compile error? This is what I tried:

```
public enum Difficulty{
    EASY(3600 * 36),
    MEDIUM(3600 * 24),
    HARD(3600 * 18),
    IMPOSSIBLE_1(3600),
    IMPOSSIBLE_2(60 * 5);

    private final int threshold;

    Difficulty(int seconds){
        threshold = seconds;
    }

    public int getThreshold(){
        return threshold;
    }

    public static Difficulty default(){
        return MEDIUM;
    }
}
```

It told me I needed an identifier before `default()`. What does that mean?

Comment: `default` is a reserved word in Java. You need to rename your method.

Comment: One hack is to call it `defau1t()` but that is more likely to be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

`default` is a reserved word in Java, used to provide the default implementation of an interface. Just use a name that isn't a reversed word, such as `defaultValue` and you should be fine:

```
public static Difficulty defaultValue() {
    return MEDIUM;
}
```